# Can this diagnostic card be used to to test a laptop motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

This card has a usb connection so could potentially be used to plug into a laptop at boot. I'd like to know if I have any hope of diagnosing problems on the motherboard with this card or if its too old / not suited to the task.

The card lights up and is responsive when plugged into the motherboard at power on.

The laptop board in question also has a a mini pcie slot. Would an equivalent card for that slot be any better?

I'm keeping this brief in case it is off topic. If you are tempted to vote to close, please let me know if it would be accepted with further information. Also, a link to an appropriate place to ask this question would be appreciated.

The card is Chinese in origin and the patent number on the board led me to [this manual](http://www.61131568.com/download/2in1-E.pdf)

[image]

Comment: AFAIK such cards show a code number derived from the activities on the (PCI) bus. AFAIK no such activities are visible on an USB bus. And note that the connector seems to be the flat (host) type, so you can't connect it to a computer, at least not with an official cable.

Comment: Thanks. It comes with a cable which has standard USB connectors on each end i.e not the kind you would use to connect a peripheral like a printer.